# Question about the definition of Surjective Functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

In the definition of surjective functions, it's often stated that, "every element in the codomain must map to an element in the domain".

Is the converse true? Why does it seem messier with the converse?

How can we talk about it in terms of domain -> codomain?

Comment: You are talking about the converse statement "Every element in the domain must map to an element in the codomain". If this wasn't the case either our codomain is incorrect or we do not have a function

Comment: The actual definition of a surjective function is different. It is not "every element in the codomain must map to an element in the domain", but "every element in the codomain must be mapped to by some element in the domain under f".

Comment: Those sound completely identical to me Kenneth

Comment: It is important that it is the elements of the *domain* that get mapped to elements within the *codomain* by f. How your statement is worded now, it seems as if though elements from the *codomain* get mapped to elements within the *domain* by f, which is the other way around.

Comment: well that was partly why I was confused - I wanted to know if there was a way to word it so we can talk about domain maps to codomain in terms of surjective functions

Comment: Note that in general it is impossible to `invert' a function f to create a new function g, such that g maps from the codomain to the domain. One of the two reasons this might fail is because the function f is not surjective. If f is not surjective, then by definition there is some element y in the codomain that does not get mapped to by f. So where should g(y) get sent to? It will be good to have a visualisation for this, such as the one given in Novice's answer.

Answer (score 0):

A function $f \colon X \to Y$ by definition must take *every* $x \in X$ and send it to an element $y \in Y$. The essence of surjectivity, which is a property not possessed by all functions, is that $f$ will "hit" every element of $Y$.

See the photos at the beginning of this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) article.